# What email account a google analytics was created with

Tags: email, analytics, account, recovery

I need to find out what email account a google analytics account was created with. I own the domain. But the analytics was created by a developer I do not know.

Answer (score -1):

Even with the GA id, there is no way to find out. It's a security/privacy issue.

Comment: I am the owner of the domain. I should be able to get access to my domains analytics.

Comment: But you're not the owner of the associated, existing analytics account. Sorry, but your ownership does not help.